# Inlining require statements in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs

I need to be able to run arbitrary node.js javascript in a browser. This javascript may contain `require()` statements. I'd like to be able to inline the script from required modules, on the server, before sending it off to the client.

One caveat is that the javascript that I need to send the client is in memory, stored as a string, not sitting in a file. I was thinking of using something like **browserify** for this. I'm not sure how to pass browserify a string though.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Does this way involve browserify?

Comment: The notion of running "node.js javascript in a browser" is kind-of nonsensical. A browser is a browser, and Node is Node. The browserify package is for providing browser features to JavaScript running in Node.

Comment: Are you talking about node-webkit, some kind of ajaxy rpc magic, or usage of pure code? If you have code as string (BAD IDEA), that's what `eval` is for.

Comment: @pointy I thought the point of browserify was to provide a package manager in a browser environment?

Comment: @Pointy I hope I've just worded my situation badly. FWIW here's more detail. Sorry, it's a little gory. I have a view in [jsx](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). I transform that to normal javascript, which is stored in memory. This may contain `require()` statements (it's a view in express). I need to send this javascript off to the client, to be run there. So I need to do something about the `require()` statements.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't want to `eval` the code in the node.js server environment. I want to make the code suitable for execution in a browser, by inlining(is that the right word?) the `require()` statements.

Comment: Are you trying to require something that a browser is in principle unable to do?

Comment: @JanDvorak ah you're probably right; sorry I'm not really properly awake this morning

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found what I need to do.

It is using browserify after all.

I think I'll do something like this:

```
var b = require('browserify')();
b.require(streamWithMyJavascript, {basedir: '.'});
b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

This will, for example, write my inlined javascript to the console, with all requires removed.